# Github Actions apt install graphicsmagick gives the error "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory"

Tags: ubuntu, continuous-integration, github-actions, apt, graphicsmagick

Github Actions apt install graphicsmagick gives the error "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory".

graphicsmagick is a dependency for one of our builds.

Using GitHub Actions ubuntu-latest runner.

Command used: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install graphicsmagick -y`.

Tried:

- `sudo apt install graphicsmagick -y`
- `sudo apt install graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat -y`
- manually downloading the .tar.gz and running ./configure && ./make

All options result in the same error message.

Need assistance to resolve.

Comment: Are you building a Ruby app? What does your workflow look like? Please include the complete logs of that step where it's failing.

Comment: ---
2023-06-26T07:46:02.1111740Z NEEDRESTART-KSTA: 1
2023-06-26T07:46:04.9395260Z Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
2023-06-26T07:46:04.9433784Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 10.
2023-06-26T07:46:04.9451338Z ##[debug]Finishing: Build
---


Building an Android app. 

The build step is: `sudo apt install graphicsmagick -y` and then it runs our `bundle exec fastlane ...` command. `graphicsmagick` is required for the build.

In any case, I got it to work with `linuxbrew` but had to set the env variable `HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP: true`.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76553974/edit) your question include your complete workflow. The error logs in your above comment don't seem to be related to `apt` per se. They must be coming from `bundle` command which needs Gemfile to work with. Without your workflow, it's hard to say what the actual issue is. Maybe, your checkout step is missing, or the command may be running from an incorrect location, or maybe you're using `actions/setup-ruby` action with `bundler: true`, etc.